# Filtering after Multi Indexing in pandas iterable indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a subset of my dataFrame object using pandas or any other python liberary using Hierarchical indexing that can be iterable depending on number of rows I have in one of the column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(address)

    trajectory  frame   x           y                                               

        1       1       447,956     2,219
        1       2       447,839     2,327
        1       3       449,183     1,795
        1       4       450,444     1,833
        1       5       448,514     1,708
        1       6       451,532     1,832
        1       7       448,471     1,759
        1       8       450,028     2,097
        1       9       448,215     2,203
        1       10      449,311     2,063
        1       11      451,745     1,76
        1       12      450,827     2,264
        1       13      448,991     2,208
        1       14      452,829     3,106
        1       15      448,688     1,77
        1       16      449,844     1,951
        1       17      450,044     1,991
        1       18      449,835     1,901
        1       19      450,793     3,49
        1       20      449,618     2,354
        2       1       445.936     7.219
        2       2       442.879     3.327
        3       1       441.283     9.795
        4       1       447.956     2.219
        4       3       447.839     2.327
        4       6       449.183     1.795
```

In this DataFrame, let say there are 4 columns, names: 'trajectory', 'frame, 'x' and 'y'.  Number of 'trajectory' can be different from one dataframe to another. Each 'trajectory' can have multiple frames between 1 and 20, where they can be sequential from 1-20 or with some missing frames as well. Each frame has its own value in the column 'x' and 'y'.

My aim is to create a new dataframe where I can have only those 'trajectory' where the 'frame' values is present for all the 20 rows. As the number of rows in 'trajectory' and 'frame' columns are changing, so I would like to have a code that can be used in such conditions.

```
df_1 = df.set_index(['trajectory','frame'], drop=False)
```

Here, I did a heirarchical indexing using 'trajectory' and 'frame' and then I found that 'trajectory' number 1 and 6 have 20 frames in them. So I could manually select them using the following code.

```
df_1_subset = df_1[(df1['traj']== 1)|(df1['trajectory']== 6)]
```

However, I have multiple csv files where in each Dataframe, the 'trajectory' that will have 20 rows in the 'frame' column will be different, so I will have to do this manually. I think, there must be a better way, but I just can not seem to find it. I am very new to coding and I would really appreciate anybody's help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iif need filter `trajectory` level for `1` or `6` use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df_1_subset = df_1[df1.index.get_level_values('trajectory').isin([1,6])]
```

---

If need filter `trajectory` level for `1` and `frame` for `6` select with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with tuple:

```
df_1_subset = df_1.loc[(1, 6)]
```

Alternative:

```
df_1_subset = df_1.loc[(df1.index.get_level_values('trajectory') == 1) | 
                        (df1.index.get_level_values('frame') == 6)]
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, Thank you so much for the prompt help. However, The first code did not work and was showing syntax error (in jupyter notebook). The second and the alternative are working but I can not use them as they are not iterable. As I mentioned in the post, the trajectory and frame both can be have different number of rows under them, This is just one example that I posted here. so mentioning 1,6 or using code like 'trajectory' ==1 would only take that particular trajectory. Thank you again for the helping hand. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @RahulKaushik - sorry, I forget for first `(`, need remove it like `df_1_subset = df_1[df1.index.get_level_values('trajectory').isin([1,6])]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works great. I use .isin method and give the values of trajectories manually like in this case 1 and 6. but they will be different with a different csv file. I was wondering if is.in method take any variable such as 'x' as input because then I can assign to a list which will have this info and then I can automatize it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am very new to stack overflow. Your code did help me with the issue. Thanks